# can able to pick suburbs from google address

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Peninsula+Rd,+Kelvin+Heights,+Queenstown+9300,+New+Zealand/@-45.0354441,168.7038649,17z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0xa9d51e030d9eb623:0x5376ee763169f01e

Can you tell me what type is use for kelvin heights?

like peninsula = street

queenstown = city

9300 = postal code

New Nealand = country

kelvin heights = ?

because i used neighbourhood, sublocality, and so on but nothing get the kelvin heights from address, though everything else is getting like country, locality/city, postal code, and so on.

this is main code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
"use strict";

var autocomplete,autocomplete2;
var options = {
    types: ['(cities)'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'uk'}
};
var componentForm = {
    establishment:'long_name',
    street_number: 'short_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_2: 'long_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name',
    postal_code_prefix:'short_name',
    neighborhood: 'long_name'
};

if ( google_map_submit_vars.enable_auto ==='yes' ){  
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
  /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('property_address')),
    {   types: ['geocode'],
        "partial_match" : true
    }
);
// When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
// populate the address fields in the form.
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
     var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    fillInAddress(place);
});
    autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('property_city_submit')),
        {    types: ['(cities)']        }
    );

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete2, 'place_changed', function() {
         var place = autocomplete2.getPlace();
        fillInAddress(place);
    });
}
function fillInAddress(place) {

    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];

        var temp='';
        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];

        if(addressType=== 'street_number' || addressType=== 'route'){
          //  document.getElementById('property_address').value =  document.getElementById('property_address').value +', '+ val;
        }else if(addressType=== 'neighborhood'){
             $('#property_area').val(val);
        }else if(addressType=== 'postal_code_prefix'){
            temp = $('#property_zip').val();
            $('#property_zip').val(val+" "+temp)
        }else if(addressType=== 'postal_code'){
            temp = $('#property_zip').val();
            $('#property_zip').val(val+" "+temp)
        }else if(addressType=== 'administrative_area_level_2'){
            $('#property_region_submit').val(val);
        }else if(addressType=== 'administrative_area_level_1'){
            $('#property_region_submit').val(val);
        }else if(addressType=== 'locality'){
            $('#property_city_submit').val(val);
        }else if(addressType=== 'country'){
            alert('c');
            $('#property_country').val(val);
        }else{ 

        }
    }
}

autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
  /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('property_city_submit')),
    {    types: ['(cities)']        }
);

// When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
// populate the address fields in the form.
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete2, 'place_changed', function() {
     var place = autocomplete2.getPlace();
    fillInAddress(place);
});

jQuery('#google_capture2').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    codeAddress_child();  
});  

function codeAddress_child() {
    var address   = document.getElementById('property_address').value;
    //var e = document.getElementById("property_city_submit"); 
    //var city      = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    var city=jQuery("#property_city_submit").val();

    var full_addr= address+','+city;
    if(  document.getElementById('property_region_submit') ){
        var rgn     = document.getElementById('property_region_submit').value;
        if(rgn){
             var full_addr=full_addr +','+rgn;
        }
    }

    if(  document.getElementById('property_country') ){
        var country   = document.getElementById('property_country').value;
        if(country){
             var full_addr=full_addr +','+country;
        }
    }   


    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': full_addr}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: 'Latitude: ' + results[0].geometry.location.lat() + '<br>Longitude: ' + results[0].geometry.location.lng()  
                 });

                infowindow.open(map,marker);
                document.getElementById("property_latitude").value=results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                document.getElementById("property_longitude").value=results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        } else {
                alert(google_map_submit_vars.geo_fails + status);
        }
    });
}


/////////////////////////////////////// search code

});
```

Comment: it seems to be `sublocality_level_1`

Comment: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_geocoding-reverse2postcodeD.html?lat=-45.0354441&lng=168.7038649